# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createComponentInstance' of 'vue.ssrUtils' as it is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

After I upgraded from  Vue 2 to Vue 3 using vue-next, I got this error caused by `@vue/server-renderer`.

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createComponentInstance' of 'vue.ssrUtils' as it is null.
  at Object../node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js (/path-to-project/dist/js/webpack:/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:125:1
```

Looking at `node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:125:1`

```
var vue = require('vue');
// some code here ...
const { createComponentInstance, /* other extracted vars*/ } = vue.ssrUtils; // line 125
```

It seems like `vue.ssrUtils` is `null`!

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: From [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2244#issuecomment-707366281): "The ssrUtils object in Vue 3 only gets exported in CommonJS builds. When the target isn't node, Webpack by default uses the esm file if defined in the module field of a package.json (which `@vue/runtime-core` does define). The fix was adding this line to my webpack config: `resolve: { mainFields: ['main', 'module'] }`". That Webpack config might be overly broad and defeat the tree-shaking benefit of ESM modules.

Comment: Using a fresh vue 3 install with the vue cli there *is* no webpack config file that I can find.  Where does this fix need to be exactly?

Comment: @NathanielFord vue cli creates its own config called `vue.config.js`, you should place it to `configureWebpack` field

Answer (score 0):

The error occures because vue@next provides an esm version which strips ssr apis, If you check vue@next package.json you'll find these codes:

```json
{
    // ...
    "main": "index.js",
    "module": "dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js",
    // ...
}
```

same with @vue/runtime-dom and @vue/runtime-core

ssrUtils is exposed in @vue/runtime-core's "main" file, while "module" expose "null".

if your project is running with pure nodejs, the "module" option will never be used because node.js doesn't recognize it，so this issue only exists while you build your project using other tools.

If you're using webpack, this option will change the priority of main/module/browser options and fix your problem:

```json
{
    // ...
    "resolve": {
        "mainFields": ["main", "module"]
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: in which file should the resolve object be added?

Comment: @Anirudh In the webpack config file.